# Tab JavaScript for BootStrap 2.0 not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the new Bootstrap 2.0 CSS files and JavaScript files up and working and I cannot seem to get the tab script to work.  It just displays as though nothing is happening and I can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong.
My HTML is as follows

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#parts" data-toggle="tab">Parts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#partCompare" data-toggle="tab">Part Compare</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="parts" >
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>
                Parts
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchPart", "Part", null, new AjaxOptions {     UpdateTargetId = "update_panel" }, new { @class = "pull-right" }))
                {
                    <input type="search" name="search" id="search" value />
                    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
                }
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid" id="main">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div id="navigation" class="span2">
                    <ul class="treeview"/>
                </div>
                <div id = "mainwindow" class="span10">
                    <div id="update_panel"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="partCompare">This is the part Compare Tab!!!</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.tabs').tab('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It appears as though when I look at the html in Chrome's developer tools the <div> tag for the second tab gets moved inside the <div> tag for the first tab making the whole thing not work.  This also happens in IE 9.  I have commented out all the javascript and css and it still makes this change.  What could be causing this?

Comment: The following line was causing my second problem <div id="update_panel"/> when it was replaced with <div id="update_panel"></div> it started behaving better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing a css class (nav) and the 'tabs' should be called 'nav-tabs' now, one of the changes since Bootstrap 1.4:

```
Tabs and pills now require the use of a new base class, .nav, on their <ul>
```

They give this example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

-update-

The jQuery selector is missing the 'a' part:

```
$(function () {
  $('.tabs a:last').tab('show')
})
```

Likely you want to change :last in :first to activate the first tab.

Comment: that fixes the tab portion at the top, but does not fix the content switching back and forth.

Comment: your update helps, but the script isn't hiding the info in the second tab and it's not switching anything when I click the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using? The tabs in 2.0 use .on(), added to jQuery in version 1.7.

I had the same problem, jQuery 1.5.1 and tabs worked fine under bootstrap 1.4, but quit with 2.0. Upgrading jQuery fixed my problem.

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7.1.  It has gotten weirder and I will update the main post as to what I have found shortly.

Comment: Do you have the whole tab UL and separate content sections enclosed in a div with class="tabbable" ?

Comment: See my comments on the original post for what the problem was in addition to the problem that the original answer solved.